# Silverlight Canvas Newbie Question

Tags: silverlight

I have a Silverlight user control that has several canvas controls within a Stack Panel.  I know that I can set the Width and Height of each canvas panel manually in the Xaml, but I want them to be the same size.

Is there some way I can define a property in a UserControl.Resources location:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Setter Property Name="aWidth" Value="50" />
    <Setter Property Name="aHeight" Value="50" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
<Canvas x:Name="canvas1" Width="{StaticResource aWidth}" Height="{StaticResource aHeight}" />
<Canvas x:Name="canvas2" Width="{StaticResource aWidth}" Height="{StaticResource aHeight}" />
</StackPanel>
```

so that each panel is the same width and height and I only have to set it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this xml namespace declaration to the root of your Xaml:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

And change your resources to look like the following:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <sys:Double x:Key="aWidth" >50</sys:Double>
    <sys:Double x:Key="aHeight" >50</sys:Double>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Now you should be able to use the {StaticResource}s the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Grid instead

```
<Grid Width="600" Height="300">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />          
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas1"  />
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas2" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

Both the Canvas's will have the height of 300 and width of 300.